# Alt-tab window list displays Android virtual devices as "Unknown"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, android

I'm running multiple Android virtual devices at the same time. Although all of them have proper names in AVD Manager, on Alt-Tab list all of them are displayed as "Unknown".

[image]

Is there any way to assign definite names for them?

I'm running Pop!_OS 18.10 (based on Ubuntu) with GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this behavior is only in the new GNOME's `Switch applications` mode.
I assigned `Super`+`Tab` shortcut to `Switch windows` and now I get what I wanted:
[image]